# Is there a countable Fourier transform for infinite sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis

There's the discrete Fourier transform and the continuous one, but where's the one for infinite sequences.  Let $(a_i) \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of complex numbers.  The naive ways of defining it, say like  $\hat{(a_i)}(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k e^{-i2\pi k / n}$ (or something similar), seem to not behave like the known Fourier transforms, or I suck at math.  In either case, I need to know this!

I understand some vector spaces don't have orthonormal bases.  Well what's the best we can do then?

What about

$\hat{(a_i)}(n) = \lim {N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N a_k e^{i2\pi k/N}$

Might work.  But probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Pedro Tamaroff I found this: [Fourier sequence transform](http://web.abo.fi/fak/mnf/mate/kurser/fourieranalys/chap4.pdf).  That makes sense, I kept thinking the variable of the function $\hat{f}$ would be an integer, but of course it should actually be a complex number.

Let $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, be a sequence.

Then define $$\hat{f}(\omega) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{- \omega i 2 \pi n}$$.

What if we let $b_k = \hat{f}(1/k)$.  Then 
$$
b_k = (\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_{kn + 1}) e^{-i2\pi/ k} + (\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{kn+2} )e^{-i2\pi2/k} + \dots \text {finite sum}
$$

The series might have to converge absolutely though for that to work.

Comment: I believe this is generally called the [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series).

Comment: This is actually more like a trigonometric series.